# How to setup each uicollectionview cell to open new view with corresponding text

Tags: uilabel, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

so I have my uicollectionview setup with 40 cells. What I would like to do is when a cell is tapped it opens new view with 2 labels, each with 40 corresponding different texts.
So I'm thinking of having
NSArray1 for label1
NSArray2 for label2
Then get labels to check index of cell and display its text at that index.
Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily. So far your thought is in the right direction. Keep data in arrays(use a dictionary will be better since you can avoid two different arrays and get a well structure) and keep track of the selected index of the item.

You have create a property in the detailViewController to store the selected item number.

```
 - (void)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    detailViewController.selectedItem = indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Just a thought would it be possible to get a nsinteger from 'didselect' method then use that in 'prepareforsegue' method somehow?

Comment: ya it is possible.. either you can store indexPath.row in an instance variable from didSelectRow or you can call indexPathForSelectedRow directly from prepareForSegue

Comment: The way I've done it is have integer value in detailviewcontroller, get value from prepareforsegue method then use that in array objectatindex. Not sure if this is correct way but its working.

Comment: Thats correct. Passing value to the next view controller through prepareSegue is one of the proper way. Nthing wrong in that..;)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it's been almost two years since I posted this question. Time to pick up where I left off. Anyone kind enough to tell me which route I should take: A) cell opens new collectionview with full screen cells. B) just one collection view but with second layout with second custom cell. C) none of the above. Suggestions please.